# Delete, for a given sheet of a given workbook, all named ranges from this sheet based on a condition on their name

Tags: excel, vba

I would like to delete all ranged names from a worksheet (in my ambient workbook) base a criterion on their names.

If found this code :

```
Dim wkSettings As Worksheet
Set wkSettings = ThisWorkbook.Sheets("TheSheetToTarget")

For Each nm In wkSettings.Names
    If nm.RefersToRange.Parent.Name = wkSettings.Name Then
    'Do stuff
    End If
Next nm
```

but cannot succeed in adapting it as the `if` condition seems to always be valid.

Answer (score 0):

Print a few properties per named range, to decide which one would you like to use for a filter and deletion:

```
Sub TestMe()

    Dim nm As name        
    For Each nm In ThisWorkbook.Names
        Debug.Print nm
        Debug.Print nm.RefersTo
        Debug.Print nm.name
    Next nm

End Sub
```

If you put a stop and press <kbd>F9</kbd> over `nm`, it would enter "[watch window](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/office/vba/language/reference/user-interface-help/watch-window)" and there the properties of `nm` could be explored:

[image]